# Change default number of zeros for automatic conversion to scientific notation in python

Tags: python

Python [converts very small numbers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/display-scientific-notation-as-float-in-python/) automatically to scientific notation. Is there a way to globally control when this conversion should be used, i.e. the number of zeros after the decimal separator?

For example

```
print(0.01)
print(0.001)
print(0.00001)
```

will result by default in

```
0.01
0.001
1e-5
```

Now I want to set a global option like this:

```
max_num_of_zeros=1
print(0.01)
print(0.001)
print(0.00001)
```

should result in

```
0.01
1e-3
1e-5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about overriding `print` with a custom function ? (If you need `print` and cannot directly use the new one instead and just changing `max_num_of_zeros`)

I guess it is not your expected implementation (I don't know if it is possible), but it gives the same functionality.

```py
import builtins
from functools import partial

def my_print(item, max_num_of_zeros=None):
    if not isinstance(item, float) or max_num_of_zeros is None:
        builtins.print(item)
            
    elif item < 0.1 ** (max_num_of_zeros + 2):
        builtins.print(f"{item:1.0e}")
        
    else:
        string = f"{item:.10f}".rstrip("0")
        builtins.print(string)
```

then, you can do

```py
print = partial(my_print, max_num_of_zeros=1)
print(0.01)
print(0.001)
>>> 0.01
>>> 1e-03

print = partial(my_print, max_num_of_zeros=2)
print(0.01)
print(0.001)
print(0.00001)
>>> 0.01
>>> 0.001
>>> 1e-05

print = partial(my_print, max_num_of_zeros=5)
print(0.01)
print(0.001)
print(0.00001)
>>> 0.01
>>> 0.001
>>> 0.00001


# and to get back normal behavior
print = builtins.print
```